# Ik controller have no limit and keeps stretching the mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

The bone keeps pulling the mesh.

[image]

What I've tried so far: changing the vertex. sculpting doesn't work. limiting the bone location and distance. And weight painting.

[image]

None of them seem to work.

The reason I think caused it: High vertex count, Bad bone placement.

Or weight painting.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason: Instead of selecting the bones, I selected the vertex groups to inspect the cause of unwanted mesh stretching. And turns out I have some vertex groups either unwanted, Hidden, Or added in without a bone. So when I select the vertex group instead it shows that weight paint and it is in fact the area that causes the mesh to have weird stretching. hope this help people with similar problems.